# Assign custom attribute of angular directive in a Html Helper element Razor

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here I am writing an angular custom directive attribute as below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, el) {
                el.bind('blur', function () {
                    alert('hi');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

And I have an view  in which i am using razor .So my question is how to inject this directive attribute to my htmlHelper element.My Html Helper element is as follows

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control testcss", required = "true", ng_model = "Name", uib_popover = "I have a title!", popover_toggle = "focus" })
```

When i simply inject the attribute  as "my_directive" it shows "Invalid anonymous type memeber declarator".

Appreciate your help.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  You can solve this by adding `@my_directive=""` to the list in the anonymous class.  It seems when declared with an empty value, it will just add the attribute with no value (so, it will render as **input type="text" my-directive id="myID"...**).

Hope that helps!
Steve